# p:editor not shown inside p:fieldset

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:editor inside a p:fieldset. It is not shown. The fieldset is set to collapsed. When I set the p:editor outside the fieldset it is shown. When I set the fieldset to collapsed=false, then the editor is also show. what can I do to have the editor shown when the fieldset is set to collapsed=true.

```
<p:fieldset id="emailPanel" toggleable="true" collapsed="true" >
    <p:editor id="message" value="#{mybean.message}" widgetVar="editor" width="500" height="200"/>
```

I looked at http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2601 but there is no onShow thing on a fieldset.

I'm using primefaces 3.2

Comment: I am confused, you want the editor to be shown when the fieldset is collapsed?

Comment: sorry, The fieldset is initialy (first visit to page) collapsed. And when I open it I want to see the editor. But this isn't the case. Is is not shown. When I change my code and make the fieldset intialy open, then the editor is shown. Hope this makes more sense.